# Concurrency Issue when an Update stored procedure is executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

I get this error when a stored procedure is executed at the same time by two or more instances.

> Data modification failed on system-versioned table 'dbo.Table' because transaction time was earlier than period start time for affected records.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateColumn]  
    @ChangeColumn int,       
    @column3 uniqueidentifier                      
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    BEGIN TRY

        UPDATE d 
        SET changecolumn = @ChangeColumn
        FROM dbo.table2 a 
        INNER JOIN dbo.table3 ON a.column2 = b.column2 
                              AND b.column3 = @column3 
        COMMIT;
    END TRY 
    BEGIN CATCH 
        IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
        BEGIN 
            SELECT 'ERROR - The action was unsuccessful.' as MSG 

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
        END 

        INSERT INTO dbo.catcherror (UserName, ErrorNumber, ErrorState, 
                                    ErrorSeverity, ErrorLine, ErrorProcedure, 
                                    ErrorMessage, ErrorDateTime, 
                                    DatabaseName, SPID, ErrorDetails) 
        VALUES (@AuditUserName, ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_STATE(), 
                ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 
                ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETUTCDATE(), 
                DB_NAME(), @@SPID, 
                (CONCAT('@ChangeColumn:', ' ' , @ChangeColumn) + CONCAT('@column3d:', ' ' , @column3))) 

        IF (XACT_STATE()) = 1  
        BEGIN  
            PRINT N'The transaction is committable.' +  
                'Committing transaction.'  
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
        END;  
    END CATCH
END
```

How can I prevent this error from happening in the most efficient way?

Comment: dbo.Table is not referenced in the procedure.  The table alias b and d are referenced but not assigned to any table.

Comment: There are a bunch of other question out there which deal with this e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211467/error-updating-temporal-tables